# Is there a tool to manipulate pg_hba.conf programmatically (if not what comes closest)?

Tags: authentication, postgresql

I'm looking for anything above the level of programmatic file manipulation, a command or a python library. There seems to be no alternative to editing the file (assuming that http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html would mention an alternative).

Comment: I think this should be asked on the [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) SE.

Comment: @@Karl Richter, if you're happy with my answer, you can still accept it even if the question is closed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [**augeas**](http://augeas.net/docs/references/lenses/files/pg_hba-aug.html). It offers both [Python bindings](https://github.com/hercules-team/python-augeas) and a command-line interface - [**augtool**](https://github.com/hercules-team/augeas/blob/master/man/augtool.pod).

```
[dba@pgsql ~]$ augtool
augtool> defvar pghba /files/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf
augtool> ####################################
augtool> ls $pghba
#comment[1] = this is a comment
1/ = (none)
2/ = (none)
#comment[2] = this another comment
3/ = (none)
augtool> ####################################
augtool> ls $pghba/1
type = local
database = all
user = all
method = trust
augtool> ####################################
augtool> insert 01 after $pghba/2
augtool> set $pghba/01/type host
augtool> set $pghba/01/database db1
augtool> set $pghba/01/user user1
augtool> set $pghba/01/address 127.0.0.1
augtool> set $pghba/01/method md5
augtool> ####################################
augtool> save
Saved 1 file(s)
```

(Comments start with `#`)

Comment: Thanks for this. First, this use-case is `augtool -i`. Second, my pg_hba.conf is not locaed in that directory -- how do I get augtool to recognize/use the pg_hba lens for the arbitrary location? Third, I've seen the augeas documentation page for the pg_hba lens and .. Greek is easier reading: How do you figure out how to "translate" the lens documentation into commands you've used above?

Comment: I found the answers to the question marked as "Second". In augtool, I can simply use: `set /augeas/load/Pg_Hba/incl[last()+1] "/etc/postgresql_hba.conf"` followed by `load`.

Comment: @Otheus, I looked at the examples and changed them a bit.